# How to visualize trajectory_msgs?

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, jointtrajectory, trajectory-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I write a package for a robot, that has servo-motors.
How node (from my package) pulbishes JointState msgs, and i can see the visualization of my robot in rviz.
I want to use a ssc32 servo-controller, with which you can set not only the state, but also the speed of single displacement.
I find a [ros ssc32 driver](https://github.com/smd-ros-devel/lynxmotion_ssc32), and this driver takes JointTrajectory like input messages.
Is there a way to display moving model of my robot (real robot not exist yet) in rviz with using JointTrajectory?
Maybe I should use gazebo simulator?

Of course, I can write a converter JointTrajectory -> JointState, but there can be a cleaner way?

I use ros-kinetic and ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282386/how-to-visualize-trajectory_msgs?/) by [SerSav](https://answers.ros.org/users/33019/sersav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [ros-planning/moveit_visual_tools](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_visual_tools).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0